return value of a function is not iterable
I am building a project using next14.2.4 and mui5.15.20. Here are the parts of code I am getting problem at.
theme.js
"use client";
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material";
import { createContext, useMemo, useState } from "react";

//use different color palette for dark mode and white mode
export const tokens = (mode) => ({
  ...(mode === "dark"
    ? {
        white: {
          100: "#ffffff",
          200: "#fefdfc",
         //and so on
        },
        black: {
         //same as above
        },
        brown: {
          //same as above
        },
      }
    : {
        white: {
          //same as above
        },
        black: {
          //same as above
        },
        brown: {
          //same as above
        },
      }),
});

//mui theme settings
export const themeSettings = (mode) => {
  const colors = tokens(mode);

  return {
    palette: {
      mode: mode,
      ...(mode === "dark"
        ? {
            primary: {
              main: colors.black[500],
            },
            secondary: {
              main: colors.white[500],
            },
            background: {
              default: colors.black[500],
            },
          }
        : {
            primary: {
              main: colors.white[500],
            },
            secondary: {
              main: colors.black[500],
            },
            background: {
              default: colors.white[500],
            },
          }),
    },
    typography: {
      fontFamily: ["Source Sans Pro", "sans-serif"].join(","),
      fontSize: 15,
    },
  };
};

export const ColorModeContext = createContext({
  toggleColorMode: () => {},
});

// theme.js
export const useMode = () => {
  const [mode, setMode] = useState("dark");
  const colorMode = useMemo(
    () => ({
      toggleColorMode: () =>
        setMode((prev) => (prev === "light" ? "dark" : "light")),
    }),
    []
  );
  const theme = useMemo(() => createTheme(themeSettings(mode)), [mode]);
  return [theme, colorMode];
};


to use above custom theme in my project i have done following thing in my laayout.js.
import { AppRouterCacheProvider } from "@mui/material-nextjs/v13-appRouter";
import { CssBaseline, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material";
import { ColorModeContext, useMode } from "./theme";
import "./globals.css";

export const metadata = {
  title: "Blog App",
  description: "Simple blog app",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  const [theme, mode] = useMode();
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <AppRouterCacheProvider>
          <ColorModeContext.Provider value={colorMode}>
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
              <CssBaseline />
              {children}
            </ThemeProvider>
          </ColorModeContext.Provider>
        </AppRouterCacheProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}


But it says following error:
Error: (0 , _theme__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.useMode) is not a function or its return value is not iterable
How can i resolve it?
Is this the correct way to use MUI in latest Nextjs. Beause somewhere i saw we have to make .js file in src directory to use it?

In your layout.js component, you need to add "use client" at top of it.

by doing so, i cannot use metadata?

You can manage the metadata by separating the server-side and client-side logic in your Next.js project

Your layout.js is a server component, add "use client" at the top of it.

by doing so i cannot use metadata, is there any other solutions?

use your useMode and ColorModeContext.Provider inside a client component, then import the component to layout and use it, and pass children as props to the client component so that not all components below them render on the client side.
